# Unstucked electrical components motherboard

Tags: components, identification

Please tell me the name of the electrical components? 
[image]
This Kindle Fire 1st gen.

Comment: I would just call it Carl. It really looks like a Carl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be a USB ESD protection diode. I found a [Semtech RClamp1521P](http://www.semtech.com/images/datasheet/rclamp1521p.pdf) which has a ZZ marking and is really small.

Comment: The absence of this element can cause rapid discharge of the battery?
Please give advice on how to select this item.

Comment: @Maxim, no an ESD protection diode is there to protect the chips connected to lines which are touchable by a human. If you are statically charged (can be several kilovolts) and touch the USB connector you will discharge and that pulse is able to destroy chips easily. An ESD protection diode will handle that discharge, hopefully without getting destroyed. If it is damages, you replace it with an equivalent part (best would be exactly the same). Important parameters other than ESD ratings are the capacities as USB is a high speed bus.